# QWebView: Extremely laggy when dragging the map around, when using google maps

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

I used the QWebView to show a simple html page loading google maps. But when dragging the map around it's really slow at loading the images, and it doesn't seem like it caches them, as it's slow the second time also to move it around.

Anyone seen something similar and got an solution?

```
    #define MAP_HTML "<html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\" " \
    "src=\"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false\"></script>" \
    "<script  type=\"text/javascript\">" \
    "var map; function initialize(lat, lng) { "\
    "map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\"map_canvas\"), " \
    "{ zoom: 15, center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), " \
    "disableDefaultUI: true, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  });" \
    "} </script>" \
    "</head><body style=\"margin:0px; padding:0px;\" onload=\"initialize(55.786033,12.521667)\">" \
    "<div id=\"map_canvas\" style=\"width:100%; height:100%\"></div>" \
    "</body></html>"


GMapWidget::GMapWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWebView(parent)
    , m_accessManager(new QNetworkAccessManager(this))
    , m_initMap(false)
{
    connect(m_accessManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(slotNetworkReply(QNetworkReply*)));

    connect(this, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(slotLoadFinished(bool)));
    setHtml(MAP_HTML);
//  auto t = QUrl::fromLocalFile("index.html").path();

//  load(QUrl::fromLocalFile("index.html"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try adding a `QNetworkDiskCache` to your `QNetworkAccessManager` to see if it fares better:

```
QNetworkDiskCache *diskCache = new QNetworkDiskCache(this);
diskCache->setCacheDirectory("cacheDir");
m_accessManager->setCache(diskCache);
```

Comment: It didnt change anything. Still when panning and it need to load images it is slow.